# Troubles using np.delete

Tags: python, numpy

I am runnig a pipeline where I use StandarScaler and one hot encoding to transform my dataset to use it for a Machine Learning mode. Afeter using the pipeline I have to create 4 diferents data sets deleting a few columns of the array resulting of the pipeline but when I use np.delete and print the shape of the arry it shows a warning and the aoutput of the shape it is ()

```
ppto_num = presupuestos[['Año','Area Productiva','Neto Tallos','Ingreso','Prod','MO']]
ppto_cat = presupuestos[['Sede','Flor','Mes']]
num_attribs = list(ppto_num)
cat_attribs = list(ppto_cat)

num_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('std_scaler', StandardScaler()),
])

full_pipeline = ColumnTransformer([
    ("num", num_pipeline, num_attribs),
    ("cat", OneHotEncoder(), cat_attribs)
])

ppto_full = full_pipeline.fit_transform(presupuestos)
print(ppto_full.shape)
```

The result it's an array of (12931, 114) but when I use np.delete

```
tallos = np.delete(ppto_full,[111, 112, 113], 1)
print(tallos.shape)
```

The output it´s () and the warning says: DeprecationWarning: in the future the special handling of scalars will be removed from delete and raise an error
"""Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.__version__)
A = np.zeros((12931, 114))
B = np.delete(A, [111, 112, 113], 1)
print(B.shape)
```

```
1.18.5
(12931, 111)
```

There's something missing from your question, apparently.